# How to prevent QWidget::show() with QWidget::showEvent()

Tags: events, qt4, qwidget

I have a `QMainWindow` which instantiate a QWidget subclass. I want to fill my subclass with remote data, so I want to prevent the `QWidget::show()` slot, ignore it and make the request, then really show the subclass widget.

I've reimplemented `showEvent(QShowEvent *)` and made it ignore the event, a `qDebug()` show me it worked and is ignored, but still showing the widget.

What did I miss ?
Thank you for your help.

Subclass:

```
void Groups_Materials::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
 event->ignore();
 qDebug() << "Event accepted: " << event->isAccepted(); // Return: false
}
```

How it is called:

```
this->m_groupsMaterialsWidget = new Groups_Materials(this->m_parent);
this->m_groupsMaterialsWidget->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
this->m_groupsMaterialsWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
this->m_groupsMaterialsWidget->show();
```

What is written in the console when calling these methods:
`Event accepted:  false`

Answer (score 1):

Add « event->spontaneous() », if it returns « true », you just can't

> The spontaneous show events of windows are delivered afterwards.

Just call « hide() » on your QWidget subclass so it won't be shown unless you call « show() » yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately: `qDebug() << "Show event is Spontaneous: " << event->spontaneous();` prints `Show event is Spontaneous:  false` ... So I'll try your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I got an anwser alone... I was using the "Qt::Sheet" flag, which seems to make it fail.
I'm on Mac, maybe it would work on Win/Linux: [Qt-Forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23193/)